# No swap in Xubuntu 14.04 LTE with full disk/system encryption

Tags: xubuntu, swap

I'm a newbee to Linux. I installed Xubuntu 14.04 LTE on my 1.6GHz/2GB RAM/120 GB SSD HDD netbook. Everything goes smoothly, except I realized that during booting and logging in there was a warning that swap file was unavailable. I used the hints from this forum and from others to remove this, but the system still lacks swap.

Please note that I had no such issues with a similar notebook installation, during which I did not use encrypted partition etc.

So, in the netbook with issues, GParted reports the following partitions:
/dev/sda1 [keys icon] ext2  /boot  243MiB
/dev/sda2  extended     111.55 GiB
   /dev/sda5 [exclamation mark icon]  crypt-liks   111.55 GiB

So, no swap is available. Is it really an issue, or shall I used a certain file as a swap since the disk and partitions are encrypted?

I'd appreciate the suggestions from expert users.

Comment: I have a similar setup. I get an error message at startup but it goes away and the system boots. Once booted I can check that the encrypted swap is actually in use.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem on similar system :), but with only Home directory encrypted...
I just copy^paste answers from another forum:

1. Cannot reduce **lv partion** to allow for swap partition.
2. At first: on most systems today with 4GB RAM and more there is no need for a swap partition. Except, of cause, you are doign very RAM intensive things.
3. Also there is the option to create a swap file instead of a partition.
   Details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq